# Regex to match atleast one upper case letter and followed optional +/- and no special characters

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to match one upper case letter followed by optional +/- symbol

eg. The possible matches are A/A+/B/B-/C/C+ ... Z/Z+/Z-

I have tried :

```
regExp= /^[A-Z][\+,\-]?/;
```

But this is allowing special characters and double chars as well AA/AB/A$/A# etc

Here first part `[A-Z]` seems to work properly but second part `[\+,\-]?` is not working

Comment: Add a `$` at the end of your regex?

Comment: You are not using an end string anchor. Also, you don't need to escape those characters nor do you have to seperate them with a comma inside your character class >> `^[A-Z][+-]?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to escape `+` in a character class (`[...]`), and you don't have to escape `-` at the end of a character class (or the beginning, but you *do* in the middle and doing so is harmless even when not necessary). Also, you don't separate the characters in a class with commas.

If you only want to match at the start of your input, just remove the escapes and commas: `/^[A-Z][+-]?/`

If you want to match anywhere in the input, remove the start-of-input anchor: `/[A-Z][+-]?/`

If you want to match the full input, add an end-of-input anchor: `/^[A-Z][+-]?$/`